Even after setting static ip address on my ubuntu server, I am not able to connect to the server with out restarting the Network Manger
I have been trying to turn my old laptop into a server so that I can try hosting few projects to showcase, so I have installed ubuntu server and experimenting with it and I have connected to the server using the ssh connection using the ssh-key pairs and its was successful, and I have also set the IP address to be static on the Wi-Fi interface to which internet is connected. The problem is if I try connecting to the same server after being away from the server (terminated ssh client) say for 15 mins or so I am not able to connect to the server again until I restart the Network Manager on the server directly
I have tried everything like turning power saving mode on wifi in case its disabling the interface while idle and also assigned static ip address in the file 00-installer-wifi-config.yaml file in netplan and the static ip address is assigned as well.
One interesting thing to note is that when I check the server connection using ifconfig command if everything is running properly while my client is not able to connect to server everything seems fine on server perfect pinging google.com works on server, static ip available, ssh service running properly but still I need to restart Network Manager every time to connect and once I restart the Network Manager the client connects flawlessly.
